# How to use SliverAppBar in SearchDelegate in Flutter to hide the AppBar on Scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I'm trying to implement `SliverAppBar` instead of the default that `SearchDelegate` use which is a basic `AppBar`, i could implement using the SliverList and changing the theme of the `AppBar`. But i couldn't find a way to change it to `SliverAppBar`

I need to use the `SliverAppBar` so that i can hide the the `SearchDelegate`'s `AppBar` on scroll.

Below is my `SearchDelegate`:

```
class BirdFinder extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: query.isEmpty
            ? Icon(null)
            : Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
        onPressed: query.isEmpty
            ? () {
                //not yet implemented
              }
            : () {
                query = '';
              },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme != null);
    return theme.copyWith(
      primaryColor: Colors.grey[50],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text('test'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final BirdsData searchResults = BirdsData();
    final Iterable<DataArchitecture> suggestion = searchResults.birdsData
        .where((a) => a.birdSpeech.toLowerCase().contains(query));

    return BirdFindingsResults(
        query: this.query, suggestions: suggestion.toList());
  }
}

class BirdFindingsResults extends StatelessWidget {
  const BirdFindingsResults({this.suggestions, this.query});

  final List<DataArchitecture> suggestions;
  final String query;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2;
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            final DataArchitecture suggestion = suggestions[index];
            return Container(
              color: Colors.white24,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: SubstringHighlight(
                      text: suggestion.birdSpeech,
                      term: query,
                      textStyle: textTheme,
                      textStyleHighlight:
                          textTheme.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    indent: 45,
                    endIndent: 45,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }, childCount: suggestions.length),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```